# SOAP/WSDL, AXIS2 and digital signing a SOAP message

Tags: soap, wsdl, certificate, apache-axis, soapheader

We need to send a SOAP message to a webservice. This is somewhat new territory, so we are a bit confused... even when searching and reading about the subject. Here is what we know / did:

1) **We must authenticate through the use of a Digital Certificate** in Base64 (obtained issuing a CSR – Certificate Signing Request).

2) **The SOAP message must contain a Security Header** (wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext") and a Body.

3) **The WSDL file does not contain a HEADER section**, but we have the header "Field structure"

4) **We decided to use Axis2/xmlbeans**, and created the JAVA classes with https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html

5) **We can easily create the STUB and send the WSDL body element** using the provided sync/async register stub methods (i assume Axis2 will generate the correct SOAP message)

### Questions

1) **How can we add the WS-Security(?) HEADER to the SOAP message**. Do we have to manipulate the AXIS2 generated code?

2) **How can we authenticate using the Digital Certificate**?

Thanks

Comment: Ok Since you do not have a restriction on the usage of technology. Maybe you should go for CXF - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html which supports WS-Security easily. If you still want to go with Axis2 you can try Apache Rampart  http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/samples.html

Comment: I dropped AXIS2 completely... huge dependency list... absolute mess, complex. Hated the experience. Changed my implementation to JAX...

Comment: Yep. My experience with Axis2 is also very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) How can we add the WS-Security(?) HEADER to the SOAP message. Do we have to manipulate the AXIS2 generated code?

```
ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
SOAP11Factory factory = new SOAP11Factory();
OMNamespace SecurityElementNamespace = factory.createOMNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext", "wss");

OMElement usernameTokenEl = factory.createOMElement("UsernameToken", SecurityElementNamespace);
OMElement usernameEl = factory.createOMElement("Username", SecurityElementNamespace);
OMElement passwordEl = factory.createOMElement("Password", SecurityElementNamespace);
usernameEl.setText(username);
passwordEl.setText(password);
usernameTokenEl.addChild(usernameEl);
usernameTokenEl.addChild(passwordEl);

SOAPHeaderBlockImpl block = new SOAP11HeaderBlockImpl("Security", SecurityElementNamespace, factory);
block.addChild(usernameTokenEl);

client.addHeader(block);
```